# Access Flask Development Server on Sagemaker Notebook Instance

Tags: python, flask, amazon-rds, amazon-sagemaker

I would like to be able to run a flask app in development on a sagemaker notebook instance and then look at the flask application in my browser. I know what I've previously been able to configure this kind of access on ec2 by opening up the port for my ip, but I'm not finding any how to for how to do it on sagemaker, which otherwise comes with the nice user interface. How can I access the flask app running on a Sagemaker notebook instance? In general, I'm struggling to find a development framework for flask apps once the database it uses is in Amazon RDS.

Comment: I don't think you can run Flask in a Jupyter Notebook. The recommended way to run Flask is inside a .py file. Why you can't setup a .py file?

Comment: @Ángel it is in a .py file. I just like using SageMaker instances because it has a nice web GUI, lots of packages already installed, and you can use the notebooks for other things. Open to something similar on ec2 where I know I can open the right port.

Comment: @Michael, have you been able to find the solution? I'm encountering the same thing. I have a custom model in a Sagemaker notebook instancee. The notebook is calculating everything and save them down as .csv files. I only need to spin up a flask app to serve these pre-calculated csv files. I don't want create a container to repeat the data and the service. Please advise.

Comment: @GeneXu it does not appear that there is a way to do this on SageMaker. If you just need to output a csv file that's downloadable you could try writing it to S3. Alternatively, you can open ports on an ec2 instance.